# Update MongoDB document in Rails with hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rake

Curiosity led me to ask this question. Is any of you tried to update document/record with an hash of keys & values? I am using rake task here.

For example I have:

```
data = {"year" => "2015", "category" => "Action" }
movie = Movie.where(title: "Avangers").first
## some code ##
movie.save
```

Is there any easy way to update record with new keys and values in one line?

Comment: Turning an array into a hash is a no-brainer `[[:a, 1], [:b, 2]].to_h`. But its kind of unclear what you are asking. `data` is not an array - its a hash.

Comment: I am sorry. You are correct. So If I have data as hash, what is the easiest way updating the record with new keys & values?

Answer (score 0):

```
begin
  movie = Movie.where(title: "Avangers").first
  raise Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound unless movie
  movie.update!(year: "2015", category: "Action")
rescue Mongoid::Errors::MongoidError => e
   logger.error(e.message)
end
```

Comment: That is for the Mongoid ORM. It is a bit different for MongoMapper

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't so clear on the question itself. The main thing is are we able to use hash object to update record? For example (according to your code):`movie.update!data`

Comment: `year: "2015", category: "Action"` is a hash! In Ruby you can write hash arguments without wrapping them in `{}` . The result is exactly the same as if you had called `movie.update!(data)`

Comment: Thank you! However, `update` seems to work only when keys are existing in the record. What if I am trying to add new keys & values if key do not exist? I've tried using `insert!`, but perhaps it doesn't exist at all